# R - Get the value of column where column is a vector SOLVED

Tags: r, vector, indexing

##### SOLVED

I am not new to R though I find it quite difficult to get into the advanced programming part so I am looking for help.

I find it hard to put my problem into words so please excuse any inaccuracies.

In my study I conducted 90 items in randomized order. The items where displayed in groups of three and where matched to items that asked for the current mood (which is computed by 4 items)
In my dataframe the items are ordered in the way they would usually come in the questionnaire.
The order of the items in which they were asked is saved over another 90 columns of the same dataframe.

My task is to compute the mean of the three items displayed at a time and to save them into new columns.

So in general I need to

1. Look up which item was asked first, second and third (and so on later)
2. For each person individually compute the mean for the three items displayed at once
3. Save the mean into a new column.
4. look up which mood_item was asked
5. for each person individually compute the mean mood out of four items
6. save the mood into a new column.

I struggle doing this mainly in stage 2/5 where I tried to use the asked Item as a vector and use the vector in my R code. So I want to compute the mean as an iteration (for every person/row of the dataframe)

I tried it so far using this code..

my dataframe ist called "daten"
The Item I want to look up now (as it is easier) is the mood (AS01_01) which will be calculated from three Items (AS01_01, AS01_02,AS01_03,AS01_05)--> this goes on until AS30_05.
Since this is the easier task where I only need to look up one index and can use this index, index+1, index+2, index+4.

I used grep to find the index of the saved item. Though I cannot find how I will be able to get the values from the vector.

```
for (i in 1:15) {
        pos = daten[279+i]
        position = grep(paste("AS",pos,"_01", sep=""), colnames(daten))
        
        [...]
        
      }
```

since I want to make a String out of the conducted value, I used paste. Though since I get a vector the String is a long "ASc(13, 8, 1, 11, 7, 7, 2, [...], 1)_01"

Instead I need paste to work several times for each row. So I would get AS13_01 in the first and AS08_01 in the second and so on.

Additionally as you can see by this example the digits below 10 need to start with a 0 to match the variable name.

Later I want to compute and save the means by the following code

```
for (i in 1:30) {
     daten_final[paste("AS",toString(i),sep = "_")] = rowMeans(daten[c(position, position+1,    
                                                     position+2, position+4)], na.rm = TRUE)
     if (i ==30){
         daten_final = daten
     } else {
         daten_final = merge(daten_final, daten)
     }
}
```

Since it doesn't work through vectors I dont know what to do.

###### UPDATE

Here is the output for dput:

```
dput(daten[5:15, 6:16])
structure(list(AS02_01 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), AS02_02 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), AS02_03 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L), 
    AS02_04 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    AS02_05 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
    AS03_01 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
    AS03_02 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    AS03_03 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), 
    AS03_04 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    AS03_05 = c(3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), 
    AS04_01 = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = 5:15, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please make your problem reproducible by including a few rows and columns of sample data along with the desired output for that sample input. `dput()` is the easeiest way to share data, `dput(daten_final[1:10, 1:6])` will make copy/pasteable code to reproduce the first 10 rows and 6 columns of `daten_final`.

Comment: welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  here, we need to see (some of) your data.  As a general rule, when working in R, if you're thinking of using a loop, there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: though I myself find this dput data quite confusing. There are only singel values in each cell...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sample data, that gives us a clear starting place. Now, could you give us a clear goal? For the sample data you shared with `dput`, what is the desired output?

Comment: Sorry. I didnt really get the dput output..

Comment: Though I found a solution to my problem. 
I solved it and I would love to share it with you though I don't think I am even able to explain further what my problem was. Thank you anyway for your time and advise!!